# In Python is there any way to define the default value of a parameter to be based in other given parameter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, recursion, parameters

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
def some_func(a, b = a):
    if not a:
        return b
    return a + b + some_func(a-1)
```

so, because it's called recursively, I can't get `b` inside the function, I want `b` to be the value of `a` at the first time the function is called. But I don't know how to do this because the way I tried it can't reach the value of `a` in the default assignment

Comment: Is there some value such as `None` that you could use as a flag?

Comment: Can you make this a running program by showing how its called the first time? This all seems backwards for a recursive function to me. You recursively call the function and return its default value at the end?

Comment: Function defaults are defined when the function object is first built. So, you only get one chance to define it. Its common to have a default such as `None` (assuming `None` is not otherwise a valid value) to know when the parameter was not used. But then, you don't use `b` on any of the recursive calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reached what I wanted doing

```
def some_func(a, b = None):
    if b is None:
        b = a
    if not a:
        return b
    return a + b + some_func(a-1, b)
```

this way it only assigns `b` at the first time the function is called, like if `some_func(7)` is called, then `b` will be `7` until the end of the recursion, thanks for the comments y'all

Comment: Using `if b is None:` is more pythonic, so if `b` is zero it won’t trigger the if

Answer (score 0):

would something like this work?

```
a = 1
b = 2
def some_func(a, b):
    if not a:
        return b
    return a + b + some_func(a-1, b)
some_func(a, b)
```